# What's wrong with preprocessor #elif in JNI compiler?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When I try to compile my .c file in AndroidStudio with NDK I get error:

```
FAILED: C:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=mips64el-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/AndroidSDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/AndroidSDK/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64 -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -I/src/main/cpp/include -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/src/file.c.o -MF
```

And below

```
#define EcCurveFromBytes EcjaKCurveFromBytes /src/main/cpp/include\Crypto/Core/Algorithm/ecja_curve_select.h:76:9: note: previous definition is here #define EcCurveFromBytes EcjaMCurveFromBytes
```

I just try to use #if #elif preprocessor. How can I fix it?

```
#if (GFP_IMPL == GFP_IMPL_G)
#define EcCurveFromBytes EcjaGCurveFromBytes
#elif (GFP_IMPL == GFP_IMPL_K)
#define EcCurveFromBytes EcjaKCurveFromBytes
```

Stacktrace:

```
In file included from C:\Users\srgev\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication4\app\src\main\cpp\src\Crypto\Core\Bign.c:294:
../../../../src/main/cpp/include\Crypto/Core/Bign_c_impl.h:7:8: error: redefinition of 'BignLoadDefaultParameters'
bool_t BignLoadDefaultParameters( EcCurveEx ex, uint64 *pseed, bitsiz_t L )
     ^
../../../../src/main/cpp/include\Crypto/Core/Bign_c_impl.h:7:8: note: previous definition is here
bool_t BignLoadDefaultParameters( EcCurveEx ex, uint64 *pseed, bitsiz_t L )
```

Comment: Does your code actually have an `#endif` that you just failed to copy?

Comment: Is `Bign_c_impl.h` a file that you wrote?

Comment: Got distracted... but based on what you showed the first thing I would suggest is to make sure that your include file is surrounded by `#ifndef BIGN_C_IMPL_H<newline>#define<BIGN_C_IMPL_H>...<your code><newline> #endif`